# JSF one value to another

Tags: jsf

On my page I have a line that displays this line from my database table called timelogging.

```
<h:outputText value="#{timeLoggingController.selected.id}" title="#bundle.ViewTimeLoggingTitle_id}"/>
```

Then i have underneath it some input fields etc, then i require my timelogging id to be submitted with the form.
How would i assign the value i get from

`timeLoggingController.selected.id`

to my

`timeLoggingDetailController.selected.logId` ?

example of my code:

```
<h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingLabel_id}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{timeLoggingController.selected.id}" title="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingTitle_id}"/>
                </h:panelGrid>

 <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateTimeLoggingDetailLabel_timeLoggingDetail_logId}" for="timeLoggingDetail_logId" />
                    <h:inputText id="timeLoggingDetail_logId" value="#{timeLoggingDetailController.selected.logId}" title="#{bundle.CreateTimeLoggingDetailTitle_logId}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateTimeLoggingDetailRequiredMessage_logId}"/>

</h:panelGrid>
```

So what i want to do is to remove the inputText and automatically assign

```
timeLogging.selected.id
```

to

```
timeLoggingDetail.selected.id
```

at the end of my page:

```
    <h:commandLink action="#{timeLoggingDetailController.create}" value="#{bundle.CreateTimeLoggingDetailSaveLink}" /> 
</h:form>
```

Comment: first of all post full code.
In your action method timeLoggingDetailController.selected.logId=timeLoggingController.selected.id

Comment: added example of my code and how i submit it

Comment: Are you using two different controllers for the same view? Can you post their code?

Comment: Just inject one bean in other bean? What exactly is the problem you're facing?